# Performance influence of the condition expressions in "for" statement

Tags: performance, for-loop, go

Is there any performance difference between two examples below:

**1.**

```
var slice []int{ ... huge list of items... }

for i:=0; i<len(slice); i++ { .... do something ....}
```

**2.**

```
var slice []int{ ... huge list of items... }
sliceLen := len(slice)

for i:=0; i<sliceLen; i++ { .... do something ....}
```

Are the condition expressions in "**for**" statement evaluated at each iteration or only once?

Comment: Measure. That is the only way to Tell.

Comment: The two snippets probably compile to the same machine code.

Comment: @Volker I doubt testing will provide a reliable answer. I wrote my thought process below as a comment to Meny's answer.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, Yes I was suspecting that, but wanted to hear from a person more knowledgable than me. And honestly I'm curious about design choices behind the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** There is almost no difference

Good way how to test your problem is [benchmarking](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Benchmarks) provided by standard `testing` library

Create test file eg: `forcycle_test.go`

```golang
package perftest

import (
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkLenInside(b *testing.B) {
    testData := make([]int, 1000000)

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Benchmarked code start
        for j := 0; j < len(testData); j++ {
            doSth(testData[j])
        }
        // end
    }
}

func BenchmarkLenOutside(b *testing.B) {
    testData := make([]int, 1000000)

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // Benchmarked code start
        sliceLen := len(testData)
        for j := 0; j < sliceLen; j++ {
            doSth(testData[j])
        }
        // end
    }
}

func doSth(n int) {
    _ = n + n
}
```

Run benchmark

```
go test -bench .
```

Example output

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: forperf
BenchmarkLenInside-6                4543            259117 ns/op
BenchmarkLenOutside-6               4620            258069 ns/op
PASS
ok      forperf 3.811s
```

> The benchmark function must run the target code b.N times. During benchmark execution, b.N is adjusted until the benchmark function lasts long enough to be timed reliably.

As you can see in this benchmark run when you write `len` function as part of for cycle, it is just slightly slower then version out of cycle.

| Type | b.N before timed | Avg time per b.N iteration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Len in | 4543 | 259117 ns |
| Len out | 4620 | 258069 ns |

Note that several runs gives you different results where `len in` is `A` and `len out` is `B`

`A < B` or `A ≈ B` or even `A > B` is possible.

Comment: I was suspecting that they should be have similar performances but didn't have a reliable source to confirm. I'm a little bit skeptic that a test will provide a reliable answer to my question. Because looking at length of an array/slice is constant time so it may not be observable in the test performance. I vaguely remember that some other language looks at the length of the array at first iteration and keeps that in memory. I don't remember which though. I guess, only way to find out the answer is to wait for a person who is well versed in source code and can teach us  how internals work.

Comment: I liked your explanation though with all tips and tricks.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the condition expressions in "for" statement evaluated at each iteration or only once?

The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_condition) that the condition is evaluated before each iteration.

Because the value of `i` changes on each iteration, it makes sense the conditions `i<len(slice)` and `i<sliceLen` are evaluated before each iteration.

The compiler can hoist parts of the condition expression evaluation out of the loop as long as the resulting program executes as if the expression is evaluated every time. For example, the compiler can load `len(slice)` or `sliceLen` to a register before the loop and use that register in the loop.

> Is there any performance difference between two examples below

Both code snippets compare variable `i` to a value read from a variable.  In the first snippet, the value is read from the slice header length field. See [Slices: usage and internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro) if you are not familiar with how a slice is implemented.

The performance should be similar if not identical.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and links for further reading. By condition expression I really meant the "len(slice)" part, but poorly worded, I guess. So the point I'm wondering is does len(slice) part causes any penalty more than sliceLen part. In this particular case len(slice) is constant time but it can be something more complex. If that's the case, does for-loop computes that second part again and again in each iteration. Note that I'm not asking comparison with i. I'm asking second part in the comparison.

Comment: Not only is the expression `len(slice)` constant time, the expression evaluates to a value stored in the variable `slice`.   It's not something more complex and never will be.

Comment: @Kolom The two programs compile to the same code on my desktop computer.  The variable `sliceLen` is optimized out of the program.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to know. I guess the principle that says "do not optimize the code pre-maturely" holds true once again.